# I want to pass JSON data from javascript to Native iOS module in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json, react-native

I am now developing some Native UI Component in React Native.
I have no problem with passing simple data (basic data) from Javascript to Native iOS Module but I have some difficult problem with passing json data to native IOS module.

there is sample on React Native Community reference but I can't not understand enough.

for example, I want to pass the data like this.

```
data = {
session: "aaa",
token: "bbb",
security: "cccc"
};
```

all the data will be passed at the same time so I want pass this JSON data to Native iOS module .

Answer (score 2):

JSON data from react-native will be passing as Dictionary to iOS native module.

```
 RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(foo:(NSDictionary *) jsonObject)
{
    //you probably need to convert dict to your object manually like
    [self convertDictToCocoaObject:jsonObject]];
}
```

From react-native document:

> RCT_EXPORT_METHOD supports all standard JSON object types, such as:
>
> string (NSString)
>
> number (NSInteger, float, double, CGFloat, NSNumber)
>
> boolean (BOOL, NSNumber)
>
> array (NSArray) of any types from this list
>
> object (NSDictionary) with string keys and values of any type from
>   this list
>
> function (RCTResponseSenderBlock)